# Is there a difference b/w the AppForSharePointWebToolkit and AppForSharePointOnlineWebToolkit nuget packages?

Tags: sharepoint-addin

Microsoft is publishing two similarly named nuget packages that contain the App for SharePoint Web Toolkit. They are:

1. [App for SharePoint Web Toolkit (for SharePoint 2013)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AppForSharePointWebToolkit)
2. [App for SharePoint Web Toolkit (for SharePoint Online)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AppForSharePointOnlineWebToolkit/)

These are both at v2.1.3 currently.

Other than the nuget package name, is there a difference between these two packages? I've installed both side by side and have found not such difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've compared two .nupkg files (zip archives, actually) - there are minor differences in metadata (package names and so on), other files are byte-per-byte equal.

Why would anyone bother with giving a separate name to equal fileset? I think it's related to '*versionless*' nature of SP Online and upcoming release of SP 2016.

So `AppForSharePointOnlineWebToolkit` could be updated separately in future, while leaving `AppForSharePointWebToolkit` for 2013 and introducing something like `AppForSharePointWebToolkit2016` package for 2016